# How to trigger Ctrl+C key event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, jquery-events

I want to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text from a page. I first tried this:

```
$('#codetext').click( function() {
  $("#codetext").trigger({
    type:  'keydown',
    which:  99
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='codetext'>
```

I have also tried using `$(this)` instead of the selector, but the input element also has focus on it, so it doesn't run.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [ZeroClipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)... I think it works, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 3):

not sure how to trigger ctrl+c, but there's a JQuery clipboard plugin that may be of some use:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copy

`$("#elmID").copy()           // copy all text inside #elmID.`

Comment: Not sure if this still works with Flash versions > 10... that plugin is pretty old too.

Comment: Im sure it doesnt run now , i have test it .

Comment: hmm, well as fudgey said it is quite old. I recalled using it once upon a time. sorry its no use!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot trigger a cut, copy or paste programmatically in JavaScript (at least, not in most browsers). These actions can only come from the user. If you need to do this you'll need some kind of hack like the Flash-based things in other answers but I wouldn't even rely on them working forever.

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl+C** event mainly used for copy content.

I tried to trigger this event on **summernote**.

While trying, I could know that `document.execCommand('copy')` can touch this problem.

Like this you may trigger **cut**, **paste** event by using `document.execCommand('cut')` and `document.execCommand('paste')`.

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve this in summernote. Did you also try to use it on an image? Or solely on text? It doesn't seem to work for me on an image.